# Wine application cannot finish setup, keeps asking for reboot

Tags: wine

I am trying to install .NET ClickOnce application using wine, and it downloaded .NET package as requested, but keeps asking to reboot.

So far I have tried wineboot with all options, but nothing helps.

[image]

Comment: Check with `https://www.winehq.org`. Not all Windows programs are available through `wine`. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a `wine` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I was able to make it work.

I have used winetricks, created a new 32bit prefix, installed .net 4.5.2 using winetricks and on  ClickOnce page, there is a "here" link with .application extension, and once clicked it opened the application which now works.

No need to finish setup.exe however I am not sure did it contributed.

Application is working perfectly.